# Bypassing save dialog box in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to bypass the save dialog box when using the SaveFileDialog class. I want to be able to write to a document without having to prompt a user to decide if they want to save or not, the file should automatically save when they click a button.

```
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

 saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
 saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
 saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     // Code to write the stream goes here.
 }
```

I have tried removing the if statement as well as using...

```
saveFileDialog1.CreatePRompt = false;
```

Nothing seems to work... Any ideas?

Comment: Just save the file then: File.WriteAllText(path, contents);

Comment: Can you clarify, please: Do you want the save dialog box to appear at all?

Comment: The whole point in the SaveFileDialog class is to prompt the user to save. If you don't want to do that then why are you using a SaveFileDialog?

Comment: Put the code from `// Code to write the stream goes here.` in a separate class and call it instead of going through `new SaveFileDialog` part. Select that code, right-clik on selection then go to Refactor and click on Extract Method.

Comment: you misunderstand the usage of `SaveFileDialog`. It ***cannot help you save*** file, it's just a dialog allowing user to input some file path (to which some new file will be saved). After that you have the file path and use classes in `System.IO` to actually save your file at that path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bypass the overwrite prompt dialog.

In this case you can use

```
saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = false;
```

Otherwise, you don't need a SaveFileDialog and you can save your stream without using it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. The question I asked was actually two it seems. The first was how to bypass SaveFileDialog, I wanted to use saveFileDialog because it can remember the last folder it accessed and opens to that folder when performing a read/save. That being said I implemented this...

```
Directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

This will set Directory to the location of my executable.

Next I got rid of SaveFileDialog and just wrote to a file without ever prompting the user.

Thanks for all the pointers and ideas!

The end result ended up...

```
Directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Directory, false))
{
    // File contents
}
```

Works perfectly for what I need it for.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save but you need the user to pick a filename, I would use this:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
//setup properties of Dialog
bool filenamepicked = false;
while (!filenamepicked)
{
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Save file
        filenamepicked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have to use a file name.");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this will achieve the result of forcing the user to pick a filename, it feels like a hack both in code *and to the user*.

Comment: Can't question results ;)

Comment: "You have unsaved changes? Close anyway and discard changes?
[ Yes ]   [ Yep ]   [ Yeah ]"

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your answer was - the OP doesn't want to use a save dialog, you provided an answer where the save dialog must be used.

Comment: Tbf I couldn't really understand the request.